# Algorithm to generate combinations of lists with elements for every index swapped between them

Tags: algorithm, list, math, combinations

I have two lists with `N` elements each.

Let `N = 9`:

```
[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1, i1]
[a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2, g2, h2, i2]
```

Let's swap the first element of each list. There are two possibilities:

```
[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1, i1]
[a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2, g2, h2, i2]

[a2, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1, i1]
[a1, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2, g2, h2, i2]
```

For each possibility, let's swap the second element of each list. There are four possibilities:

```
[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1, i1]
[a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2, g2, h2, i2]

[a2, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1, i1]
[a1, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2, g2, h2, i2]

[a1, b2, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1, i1]
[a2, b1, c2, d2, e2, f2, g2, h2, i2]

[a2, b2, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1, i1]
[a1, b1, c2, d2, e2, f2, g2, h2, i2]
```

And so on.

What are the fastest algorithms to generate all combinations for 2 lists, and for `M` lists?
What's the name of this particular process?
What's the total number of combinations given `M, N`?

Comment: The total I think is N*N. In your example is 9*9=81. Am I wrong?

Comment: @DimitriosV.Papadopoulos I think there are many more. Maybe `2^9` or `2^18`?

Comment: @Freancesco Menzani Maybe this? 2^(total number of changed positions)

In the first example, you did 1 change and you had 2^(1) = 2 arrays as a result
In the second example, you did 2 changes (a1-a2 and b1-b2) and you had, as a result, 2^(2) = 4 arrays

If you will make 3 changes (a1-a2, b1-b2 and c1-c2) you will have 2^(3) = 8 arrays.

Do you get my point?

Comment: So, technically for every index, either they are swapped or they aren't. Right?

Comment: @vivek_23 That's right with two lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since for each position of newly formed list L1, an element could be chosen from either first or second list, there are two options for each position. The corresponding second list L2 will be formed by taking elements that were not chosen and this can be done in only one way. Thus, there are `2^N` combinations, where `N` is the length of original lists.

Using this thinking, it's easy to write a generator using `2^N` binary masks - for each `i` from `0` to `2^N - 1` we will generate a list determined by binary representation of that number. Here's a python code:

```
a = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
b = ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']
for i in range(2 ** len(a)):
  l1, l2 = [], []
  mask = i
  for j in range(len(a)):
    l1.append(a[j] if mask % 2 == 0 else b[j])
    l2.append(b[j] if mask % 2 == 0 else a[j])
    mask /= 2
  print(l1, l2)
```

prints

```
(['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'])
(['a2', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c2'])
(['a1', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b1', 'c2'])
(['a2', 'b2', 'c1'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c2'])
(['a1', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c1'])
(['a2', 'b1', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c1'])
(['a1', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b1', 'c1'])
(['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'])
```

Since the output size is `O(N * 2^N)` you cannot make an algorithm with better complexity than that.

Comment: This is only true with 2 input arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, you can use something like this (written in JS):

```
const arrayA = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1', 'f1', 'g1', 'h1', 'i1']
const arrayB = ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2', 'f2', 'g2', 'h2', 'i2']
let results = [{a: arrayA, b: arrayB}]

for (let i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {

    let newResults = []

    for (let j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        let result = results[j]

        // Copy the arrays
        let outA = result.a.slice()
        let outB = result.b.slice()

        // Get the items to switch
        let itemA = outA[i]
        let itemB = outB[i]

        // Switch positions in the new arrays
        outA[i] = itemB
        outB[i] = itemA

        // Append the new item to the results
        newResults.push({a: outA, b: outB})

    }

    results = results.concat(newResults)

}

console.log(results.length)
```

The final number will be 2 ^ N, in this case 512